# How to delete columns with zero value in each line?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file containing numeric data.
Each line has a varying number of columns. In each line, I want to delete the columns containing 0.

Below is a sample Input

```
25 60 0
29 0 10
23 0
26 43 49
1 56 7 0
21 0 64 3
```

Target Output

```
25 60
29 10
23
26 43 49
1 56 7
21 64 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
sed 's/ 0//g;s/^0 //g' file

25 60
29 10
23
26 43 49
1 56 7
21 64 3
```

it just removes the pattern `0`. if the output is fine, use -i option to do inline edit.

Comment: What if `0` is in the first column?

Answer (score 1):

Using perl:

```
$ perl -alne 'print join " ", grep { $_ != 0 } @F' file
25 60
29 10
23
26 43 49
1 56 7
21 64 3
```